# Does Manjaro provides same performance in gaming as Microsoft's Windows?

Tags: arch-linux, manjaro

I have a laptop
Spec:

- 8 GB DDR4 RAM
- I5 825OU
- MX 150 ( GT 1030 equivalent)

Can I get same performance in gaming with Manjaro, as I get in Microsoft's Windows?

Comment: This depends on may factors: the game itself, the drivers, and other things, why don't you try it out yourself first?

Comment: There is not reason why it won't be higher. Gnu/Linux is generally higher performance. However it will as @MunzirTaha says depend.